# Java - Can't break out of Loop

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

Can not break out of the while loop. What is wrong with my code?
Everything looks correct to me logically:

While (not 's' or not 'p')
---Printline: "Retype"
---ReadInput:

```
while (!answerInput.equals("s") || !answerInput.equals("p"))
{
    System.out.print("Wrong Input. Type S for Sum or P for Product: ");
    answerInput = userInput.next();
    answerInput = answerInput.toLowerCase();    
}
```

Please advise.

Comment: If you would have said *While (not 's' or 'p')* your mistake would be understandable. But how does *While (not 's' or not 'p')* make any sense?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In plain English, your code is saying:

> If  "answerInput" is something other than 's', **or** "answerInput" is something other than 'p', this expression is true.

This statement can never be false.  It's obviously either not 's' or not 'p'; it can't be two values simultaneously.  One of the two inequalities will always be true, and the entire expression will therefore also always be true.

What you should be saying is:

> If "answerInput" is something other than 's', **and** "answerInput" is also something other than 'p', this expression is true.

Which, in Java, is expressed as:

```
while (!answerInput.equals("s") && !answerInput.equals("p"))
```

Comment: Thank you Govind. It looks like not everything is so good with my logic. Had to draw all possible combinations of true/false to see where was I wrong. I hope it will stick into my head now.